# Unable to connect to azure vm with internal IP

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have two vnets that are connected using a gateway. VnET1 and VNET2. VNET2 has a VM which hosts a mongodb instance. I have a webjob running within an App service environment which is deployed into a subnet within VNET1. From this subnet i am able to access the VM in VNET2 with its DNS. But i am unable to access the VM's internal IP. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

An internal IP address is internal to a VNET, and VNETs are isolated from one another by design. See this site for a good overview.. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-overview/. If you want to connect internally you might want to consider having multiple subnets within the same VNET instead.

Answer (score 0):

At present, connecting two vnets using a gateway allows IP communication but doesn't allow DNS name resolution.  In this scenario we recommend managing a local DNS server. [This page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/) shows the requirements for using your own DNS server in Azure.

Hth, Gareth